# What is "var" in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I would like to ask what is "var" in this statement.

```
        var context = new MHC_CoopEntities();

        var lists = (from c in context.InventLists
                     select new
                                {
                                    c.InventID,
                                    c.ItemName,
                                    c.InventCategory.CategoryID,
                                    c.UnitQty,
                                    c.UnitPrice
                                }).ToList();

        ListGridView.DataSource = lists;
        ListGridView.DataBind();
```

I know that "var" can be any value. I am trying to create a helper class for this.

Comment: It isn't related to EF at all. What do you mean by "var" can be any value?

Comment: I think he meant to say any type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` has nothing to do with Entity Framework. It's a pure C# construct allowing you to define an implicitly typed object. It's explained in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx). Basically it allows the compiler to infer the actual type of the variable from the right handside of the assignment. This avoids you repeating the same type declaration twice. It is also necessary for anonymous types which do not have a name. For example:

```
var foo = new { Id = 123, Name = "anon" };
```

And this is exactly what happens in your example. In the select clause you are returning an anonymous type. So the only way is to use `var`.

In the first example:

```
var context = new MHC_CoopEntities();
```

it is equivalent to:

```
MHC_CoopEntities context = new MHC_CoopEntities();
```

because we know the type.

Comment: But what is the data type of MHC_CoopEntities if I were to pass this as a parameter? I don't think it will be right to use MHC_CoopEntities will be used right?

Comment: @Musikero31, the data type of `MHC_CoopEntities` is `MHC_CoopEntities`. So if you had to use it as parameter you would use `MHC_CoopEntities`.

Comment: So how can I create a generic helper class if I will use MHC_CoopEntities as my data type? Should it be something like the DataContext in LinQ?

Comment: @Musikero31, I don't understand what you are asking. What generic helper are you trying to create?

Answer (score 3):

It will be a new anonymous type. If you need to pass it between functions, you should declare the custom type first (I've called it `InventType`):

```
public class InventType {
  int InventId { set; get; }
  string ItemName { set; get; }
  int CategoryId { set; get; }
  int UnitQty { set; get; }
  decimal UnitPrice { set; get; }
}

var lists = (from c in context.InventLists
             select new InventType
               {
                 InventId = c.InventID,
                 ItemName = c.ItemName,
                 CategoryId = c.InventCategory.CategoryID,
                 UnitQty = c.UnitQty,
                 UnitPrice = c.UnitPrice
               }).ToList();
```

Now `var` represents `List<InventType>`.